# Illegal Start of Expression with my main class

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I'm starting a new program, and for some reason I get the following errors when I try to compile it:

```
3D.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
public class 3D {
            ^
3D.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
    public static void main(String[] args){
    ^
3D.java:5: error: illegal start of expression
    public static void main(String[] args){
           ^
3D.java:5: error: ';' expected
    public static void main(String[] args){
                 ^
3D.java:5: error: '.class' expected
    public static void main(String[] args){
                                     ^
3D.java:5: error: ';' expected
    public static void main(String[] args){
                                         ^
3D.java:20: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
7 errors
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.swing.JFrame;

public class 3D {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int height = 400;
    int width = 600;
    String title = "3D Game";

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setSize(width, height);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setTitle(title);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


}
```

I haven't really done much, and I'm not sure where these errors are coming from seeing as I'm not trying to declare a method within a method or anything like that. So, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class 3D
```

is not allowed; classes may not start with a number. The class name must be an [identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), which may not start with a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Change class name to

```
public class ThreeD {
```

A class name never starts with a numerical.otherwise compilation error.

From  [WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29)

**Rules for naming**

> Class names should be nouns in UpperCamelCase, with the first letter of every word capitalised. Use whole words — avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).